# SceneKit : How to draw an orbit trail?

Tags: scenekit

I have a central node to figure a sun, and another node orbiting around it to figure a planet. I'd like to indicate the planet orbit by a circle.

I have tried to create a Torus geometry, and this works, but the problem is that it grows when the camera closes up and vanishes when the camera is too far.

Is there a way to make the thickness of something (a torus, a bezier path) constant, whatever point of view is used in the scene?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `SCNShape`? Would that work for you?

Comment: SCNShape uses a bezier path, and gives a solid figure, where I only want the circle's outline. More, it is oriented on the Y coordinate. I want it oriented on the Z coordinate (the planet's rotation plane)...

Answer (score 5):

to get a view independent thickness you can try two things:

- use lines (will work if you want something that is always 1px wide).
- render the orbit with one single plane and a custom shader (or shader modifier). In the shader you can render a smoothed circle with a constant thickness by using the "fwidth" function (a related example can be found here: http://rubendv.be/graphics/opengl/2014/03/25/drawing-antialiased-circles-in-opengl.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you download [SceneKit slides for WWDC 2014](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/samplecode/SceneKitWWDC2014/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014551-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

The file AAPLSlideScenegraphSummary.m has a example using a plane with a png texture to obtain the effect you describe, hope it helps

Comment: It's because of this bad example that I decided to use a torus: I want the size of the orbit trail to be constant, independently of the orbit's size. Furthermore, a png image will also increase in size when the camera moves closer...